# How to get data and count in one query in mongoose

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

I tried to get notification as well as the data in one query and i tried like below but this is giving only count,

```
 Categories.find(item).count().exec(function (err, result) {}
```

Can anyone please suggest help.

Comment: You'd have to execute the `find`, and in the callback check the length of `result`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't get your data like this way as `@adeneo` said in the comment.

Use `find` to get all records and then check length of records

```
Categories.find({query},function (err, result) {
  if(!err){
    if(Array.isArray(result))
       var count=result.length;
  }
});
```

Comment: abdulbarik can  you plese see this question?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40231463/schema-hasnt-been-registered-for-model-categories-use-mongoose-modelname-s

Answer (score -1):

You can use @abdulbarik method if you want to fetch all the records.

If you are using a limit on the amount of data you need and you want the full count you can do the following:

```
Categories.count(query, function (err, count) {

        Categories.find(query)
            .limit(limit)
            .toArray(cb);
    });
```